# Why does lua not allow local lambda functions recursively calling themself?

Tags: recursion, lua, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a sort of decorator pattern in Lua, and along the way I have run into an issue regarding lambda functions calling themselves.

The following code runs fine:

```
local function foo()
    print("bar")
    foo()
end

foo()
```

However the following is not allowed:

```
local foo = function ()
    print("bar")
    foo()
end

foo()
```

The interpreter throws the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: main.lua:27: attempt to call a nil value (global 'foo')
stack traceback:
    main.lua:27: in local 'foo'
    main.lua:30: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

The lua documentation states that "the usual way to write a function in Lua, like `function foo (x) return 2*x end` is just an instance of what we call syntactic sugar; in other words, it is just a pretty way to write `foo = function (x) return 2*x end`", so it seems to me these should be equivalent.

What am I missing?

Comment: Note also that Lua has no notion of "lambda functions" or "named functions" - as you have correctly pointed out, "named" function declarations are merely syntactic sugar for assigning functions to variables. Functions have no name attached to them; they are always "anonymous". Lua figures the "name" out at run time by how it was called when giving you an error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in other words, it is just a pretty way to write `foo = function (x) return 2*x end`

Yes, that's how `function` works. `local function` works slightly differently.

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know that the `foo` named in the function is a local variable, because the full declaration of the local variable `foo` has not yet been completed. And that only happens at the end of the entire `local function` statement; until then, `foo` would refer to a global variable.

To prevent this, `local function X <stuff>` is syntactic sugar for two statements: `local X; X = function <stuff>`. You can do the same thing if you like, but the declaration of the local variable has to be a statement separate from the function expression itself.